# Does file ".bash_history" always record every command I ever issue?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to be able to look through my command history (all the way back to the beginning of the user).

Is there any guarantee that file *.bash_history* will continue to be appended to?

If there is a limit where the file will start to be truncated (hopefully from the beginning), is there a way to remove that limit?

Comment: This question is better suited for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of environment variables that control how history works in Bash. Relevant excerpt from bash manpage follows:

```
HISTCONTROL
       A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of values includes ignorespace,  lines  which
       begin  with  a space character are not saved in the history list.  A value of ignoredups causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be
       saved.  A value of ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value of erasedups causes all previous  lines  matching  the  current
       line  to be removed from the history list before that line is saved.  Any value not in the above list is ignored.  If HISTCONTROL is unset, or does
       not include a valid value, all lines read by the shell parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.   The  second  and
       subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.
HISTFILE
       The  name  of the file in which command history is saved (see HISTORY below).  The default value is ~/.bash_history.  If unset, the command history
       is not saved when an interactive shell exits.
HISTFILESIZE
       The maximum number of lines contained in the history file.  When this variable is assigned a value, the history file is truncated, if necessary, by
       removing  the  oldest entries, to contain no more than that number of lines.  The default value is 500.  The history file is also truncated to this
       size after writing it when an interactive shell exits.
HISTIGNORE
       A colon-separated list of patterns used to decide which command lines should be saved on the history list.  Each pattern is anchored at the  begin-
       ning  of  the line and must match the complete line (no implicit `*' is appended).  Each pattern is tested against the line after the checks speci-
       fied by HISTCONTROL are applied.  In addition to the normal shell pattern matching characters, `&' matches the previous history line.  `&'  may  be
       escaped  using  a  backslash; the backslash is removed before attempting a match.  The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command
       are not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of HISTIGNORE.
HISTSIZE
       The number of commands to remember in the command history (see HISTORY below).  The default value is 500.
```

To answer your questions directly:

No, there isn't a guarantee, since history can be disabled, some commands may not be stored (e.g. starting with a white space) and there may be a limit imposed on the history size.

As for the history size limitation: if you unset `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE`:

```
unset HISTSIZE
unset HISTFILESIZE
```

you'll prevent the shell from truncating your history file. However, if you have an instance of a shell running that has these two variables set, it will truncate your history while exiting, so the solution is quite brittle. In case you absolutely must maintain long term shell history, you should not rely on shell and copy the files regularly (e.g., using a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job) to a safe location.

History truncation always removes the oldest entries first as stated in the [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) excerpt above.

Comment: I think leading space is the bigger risk (a command does not enter the history by default if there are one or more leading whitespace). It can easily happen if copy-pasting from a text document. Perhaps cover that as well in your answer?

Comment: Environment vairable `HISTCONTROL` is often `ignoreboth`, meaning `ignorespace` (*"lines beginning with a space are not entered into the history list"*) and `ignoredups` (*"lines matching the last history line are not entered"*).

Comment: It is the default on [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633) and on Ubuntu. And likely in many other places.

Answer (score 3):

`man bash` is your friend: The `HISTFILESIZE` variable:

> The maximum number of lines contained in the history file.  When this variable is assigned a value, the history file is truncated, if necessary,  by  removing  the
>                 oldest  entries, to contain no more than that number of lines.  The default value is 500.  The history file is also truncated to this size after writing it when an
>                 interactive shell exits.

Comment: Is there a way to set this so there is no limit (so that it WILL fill up my hard disk if I should enter so many commands)?

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I think it would be sufficient for my purposes to set the value to an exorbitantly large value.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all commands from all sessions appended to the history instantly (so that you can use commands from one session immediately in another), you can put the following lines into your *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* file:

```
unset HISTSIZE
unset HISTFILESIZE
HISTCONTROL=erasedups

# Append to the history file. Don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# Multi-line commands should be stored as a single command
shopt -s cmdhist

# Sharing of history between multiple terminals
# The history file has to be read and saved after each command execution
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

More information about these commands can be found in *[Preserve Bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows#3055135)*

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try this sometime. I've given up on bash being able to record history the way I want it to (which is actually a sensible set of behaviors). The solution is to install zsh...

Answer (score 0):

Also note: By default, if you work with multiple login sessions (I usually have two or three [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) windows logged into the same server), they do *not* see each other's history.

Also, it appears that when I exit all the shells, the last one to exit is the one which is saved back the file (i.e., is visible when I start work the next day). So I assume Bash is keeping the history in memory and then flushes to the file on exit. At least that’s my guess based on what I see.

Comment: yes, I have noticed that the sessions save separately. Sometimes I find that a session crashes and all the commands from it were not saved! I'd like to avoid this. Is the only way to set it up so it flushes on every command? I would like the bash_history file to contain a synchronous (chronological) copy of my commands. I think flushing on every command entered should do the trick.

Comment: as in, you know of no other method? I read about something that can be set so it will flush on every command entered.

Answer (score 0):

Adam suggested that unsetting size limits doesn't cut it, but you can avoid other instances of the shell to change HISTSIZE, HISTFILESIZE, etc. by setting the "readonly" flag on them in file */etc/profile*.

```
unset HISTSIZE
unset HISTFILESIZE
readonly HISTFILE HISTFILESIZE HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL HISTIGNORE HISTTIMEFORMAT
```

Comment: But a system-wide setting(?). Is that the right way? Perhaps elaborate in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)