# Arrow-UP key history in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

In interactive terminal tools we have Arrow-UP key function to display the history of commands.Even if we 
close the tool and re-open the history remains.

But how do they do it, it should be saved some where
to get it back . can we access the file or is it specific to the terminal tool.Or thereis some other thing invloved?

Comment: `man bash` and search for `history` section. User history file is generally `~/.bash_history` but can be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, `.bash_history` is a file which stores the commands history. `HISTFILE` variable stores the location of command history file(aka `.bash_history`).

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/avinash/.bash_history
```

So the `.bash_history` file is stored in my `/home/$USER` (or `~`) directory.

Comment: Is there any maximum size limit for this file?? if size exceeds will the old entries be deleted?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8168723/3297613

Answer (score 1):

Bash stores a `.bash_history` file. Most other shells do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the shell/shell-options you are using the file is located in different places.

For example when you use `bash` the information/history is saved in `~/.bash_history`.